# Prepend last line of stdin to entire stdin

Tags: bash

Consider this script:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

cat <<EOS > "$tmpfile"
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS

cat <(tail -1 "$tmpfile") "$tmpfile"
```

This works and outputs:

```
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Let's say that our input source, rather than being an actual file, was instead  stdin:

```
cat <<EOS | # what goes here now?
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
```

How do we modify the command:

```
cat <(tail -1 "$tmpfile") "$tmpfile"
```

So that it still produces the same output, in this different context?

**NOTE:** The specific Heredoc I'm catting, as well as the use of a Heredoc itself,  is merely illustrative.  Any acceptable answer should assume that it is *receiving arbitrary data via stdin*.

Comment: stdin is *always* an "actual file" (a fifo/socket/etc is a file too; not all files are seekable). The answer to your question is either a trivial "use a temporary file" or some horror which will load the whole file in the memory. "How can I retrieve old data from a stream *without having stored it anywhere*?" cannot have a good answer.

Comment: @mosvy That's a perfectly acceptable answer if you'd like to add it.

Comment: @mosvy As Jonah has said, answers should be posted in the answer box. I know it's tricky to read any of the website at the moment, but please ignore the red that's slowly dripping over your vision and use the lower textarea.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
awk '{x=x $0 ORS}; END{printf "%s", $0 ORS x}'
```

#### Example

Define a variable with our input:

```
$ input="line 1
> line 2
> line 3"
```

Run our command:

```
$ echo "$input" | awk '{x=x $0 ORS}; END{printf "%s", $0 ORS x}'
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Alternatively, of course, we could use a here-doc:

```
$ cat <<EOS | awk '{x=x $0 ORS}; END{printf "%s", $0 ORS x}'
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

#### How it works

- `x=x $0 ORS`

  This appends each line of input to the variable `x`.

  In awk, `ORS` is the *output record separator*.  By default, it is a newline character.
- `END{printf "%s", $0 ORS x}`

  After the we have read in the whole file, this prints the last line, `$0`, followed by the contents of the whole file, `x`.

Since this reads the whole input into memory, it would not be appropriate for large (*e.g.* gigabyte) inputs.

Comment: Thanks John.  So is it not possible to do this in a way analogous to my named file example in the OP?  I was imagining the stdin being duplicated somehow... sort of the way `tee` does, but of a stdin and a file, we'd be piping the same stdin into two different process substitutions.  or anything that would be roughly equivalent to that?

Answer (score 5):

If stdin points to a seekable file (like in the case of bash's (but not all other shell's) here documents which are implemented with temp files), you can get the tail and then seek back before reading the full contents:

*seek* operators are available in the `zsh` or `ksh93` shells, or scripting languages like tcl/perl/python, but not in `bash`. But you can always call those more advanced interpreters from `bash` if you have to use `bash`.

```
ksh93 -c 'tail -n1; cat <#((0))' <<...
```

Or

```
zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/system; tail -n1; sysseek 0; cat' <<...
```

Now, that won't work when stdin points to a non-seekable files like a pipe or socket. Then, the only option is to read and store (in memory or in a temporary file...) the whole input.

Some solutions for storing in memory have already been given.

With a tempfile, with `zsh`, you could do it with:

```
seq 10 | zsh -c '{ cat =(sed \$w/dev/fd/3); } 3>&1'
```

If on Linux, with `bash` or `zsh` or any shell that uses temp files for here-documents, you could actually use the temp file created by a here-document to store the output:

```
seq 10 | {
  chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 # only needed in bash5+
  cat > /dev/fd/3
  tail -n1 /dev/fd/3
  cat <&3
} 3<<EOF
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat <<EOS | sed -ne '1{h;d;}' -e 'H;${G;p;}'
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
```

The issue with translating this to something that uses `tail` is that `tail` needs to read the whole file to find the end of it.  To use that in your pipeline, you need to

1. Provide the full contents of the document to `tail`.
2. Provide it *again* to `cat`.
3. In that order.

The tricky bit is not to duplicate the document's content (`tee` does that) but to get the output of `tail` to happen before the rest of the document is outputted, without using an intermediate temporary file.

Using `sed` (or `awk`, as [John1024 does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509626/116858)) gets rid of the double parsing of the data and the ordering issue by storing the data in memory.

The `sed` solution that I propose is to

1. `1{h;d;}`,  store the first line in the hold space, as-is, and skip to the next line.
2. `H`, append each other line to the hold space with an embedded newline.
3. `${G;p;}`, append the hold space to the last line with an embedded newline and print the resulting data.

This is quite a literal translation of John1024's solution into `sed`, with the caveat that the POSIX standard only guarantees that the hold space is at lest 8192 bytes (8 KiB; but it *recommends* that this buffer is dynamically allocated and expanded as needed, which both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` is doing).

---

If you allow yourself to use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo mypipe
cat <<EOS | tee mypipe | cat <( tail -n 1 mypipe ) -
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
rm -f mypipe
```

This uses `tee` to send the data down `mypipe` and at the same time to `cat`.  The `cat` utility will first read the output from `tail` (which reads from `mypipe`, which `tee` is writing to), and then append the copy of the document coming directly from `tee`.

There's a serious flaw in this though, in that if the document is *too large* (larger than the pipe's buffer size), `tee`'s writing to `mypipe` and `cat` would block while waiting for the (unnamed) pipe to empty.  It would not be emptied until `cat` read from it. `cat` would not read from it until `tail` had finished. And `tail` would not finish until `tee` had finished.  This is a classic deadlock situation.

The variation

```
tee >( tail -n 1 >mypipe ) | cat mypipe -
```

has the same issue.

Comment: The `sed` one doesn't work if the input has only one line (maybe `sed '1h;1!H;$!d;G'`). Also note that several `sed` implementations have a low limit on the size of their pattern and hold space.

Comment: The named pipe solution is the kind of thing i was looking for. The limitation is a shame.  I understood your explanation except for “And tail would not finish until tee had finished” — could you elaborate on why that’s the case?

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool named `pee` in a collection of command-line utilities usually packaged with the name "moreutils” (or otherwise retrievable from its [home website](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)).

If you can have it on your system then the equivalent for your example would be like:

```bsh
cat <<EOS | pee 'tail -1' cat 
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
```

Ordering of the commands run through `pee` is important because they get executed in the sequence provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order. Then this will work `cat lines | tee >(tail -1)`.
As others have said. You need to read file twice, or buffer the whole file, to do it in the order you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
cat <<EOS # | what goes here now? Nothing!
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS
```

Since the whole thing is literal data (a "here-is document"), and the difference between it and the desired output is trivial, just massage that literal data right there to match the output.

Now suppose `line 3` comes from somewhere and is stored in a variable called `lastline`:

```
cat <<EOS # | what goes here now? Nothing!
$lastline
line 1
line 2
$lastline
EOS
```

In a here doc, we can generate text by substituting variables. Not only that but we can calculate text using  command substitution:

```
cat <<EOS
this is template text
here we have a hex conversion: $(printf "%x" 42)
EOS
```

We can interpolate multiple lines:

```
cat <<EOS
multi line
preamble
$(for x in 3 1 2 3; do echo line $x ; done)
epilog
EOS
```

In general, avoid text processing the here doc template; try to generate it using interpolated code.

Comment: I honestly can't tell if this is a joke or not.  The `cat <<EOS...` in the OP was just an example standin for "catting an arbitrary file," to make the post specific and the question clear. Was that really not obvious to you, or did you just think it would be clever to interpret the question literally?

Comment: @Jonah The question clearly says "[l]et's say that our input source, rather than being an actual file, was instead stdin:". Nothing about "arbitrary files"; it's about here docs.   A here doc is not arbitrary. It's not an input to your program, but a piece of its syntax that the programmer chooses.

Comment: I think the context and existing answers made it clear that was the case, if only because for your interpretation to be correct you literally had to assume that neither I nor any of the other posters who replied realized that it was possible to copy and paste a line of code.  Nevertheless, I will edit the question to make it explicit.

Comment: @Jonah I do not agree with the notion that answers clarify the question. I have extended the answer with more useful material, as I had intended before being pre-empted with other activities.  Sometimes programmers indeed do not realize they can just modify the literal string in their code; they subject it to various one-off run-time manipulation only to end up with something that could just have been written in it place. Seen it more than once.

Comment: Kaz, thank you for the reply, but note even with your edit, you are missing the intention of the question.  You are receiving *arbitrary multiline input via a pipe*.   You have no idea what it will be. Your task is to output the last line of input, followed by the entire input.

Comment: @Jonah I know what the data will be because it's right there in the program as a here doc. If you don't want that, don't put here docs into the question, or say that the data comes from some arbitrary command: `unknown_command | what do I put here`.    That moves the goal-posts too much, IMHO; you should ask that in a separate question.

Comment: Kaz, the input is there only as an example.  Most people, including myself, find it helpful to have an example of real input and expected output, rather than only the abstract question.  You are the only one who was confused by this.

Comment: @Jonah It's clear enough that real data isn't `line 1`, `line 2`, `line 3`.  It's not clear that the real data isn't in here-document syntax at all.  It's the wrong example syntax.   Is your question really about the shell? Or is that just an example; your real program is actually in Python?

Comment: What you're failing to grasp here is that this is not your blog; you don't own the question. SO questions are supposed to be a form of content that is useful to future visitors.  All plausible interpretations of a question are valid; it's not your privilege to dictate that, even though you authored the first few drafts of the question.

Comment: I've updated the note to make that explicit as well.  Your "blog" accusation is without foundation.  One must always make reasonable assumptions about interpretation.  You say "It's clear enough that real data isn't line 1, line 2, line 3", but tomorrow another "Kaz" may arrive and assume that's real, fixed data.  It would be no less surprising from my POV than your misinterpretation.  I could add a note about that too.  But clarifying what's already clear hurts readability.  So you do your best to be clear, and then clarify *actual* confusion, as I have done in response to your confusion.